# Pass a character to a function and return how many employee name start with accepted character?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a function to pass a character and return count of employee name start with accepted character.Issue is when I am executing the PLSQL function using PLSQL block the "PLS-00201: identifier 'G' must be declared" occurs

I have executed the function using select statement and output is displayed successfully but when I am trying to execute fucntion using PLSQL block Error: PLS-00201: identifier 'G' must be declared occurs

```
create or replace function charcount(v_char in varchar2)

return varchar2

is

v_character number;

begin 

select count(*) into v_character from employees where substr(First_name,1,1)= v_char;

return v_character;

end;
```

Executing the PLSQL function using PLSQL block:

```
declare 

 v_char char;

 v_count number;

begin

 v_char:=&v_char;

 v_count:=charcount(v_char);

 dbms_output.put_line(v_count);

end;
```

Enter the substitution variable

```
v_char=G.

output=11.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `'&v_char'` instead of `&v_char` in your calling block. `&` variables are replaced using literal substitution - they are not like normal program variables.

```
declare 
    v_char varchar2(1) := '&textinput';
    v_count number;
begin 
    v_count := charcount(v_char);    
    dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
end;
```

Note that in PL/SQL you can assign a value when declaring a variable, which saves a step later.

Also I corrected `char` to the standard Oracle string type, `varchar2`.

For readability I prefer to leave a space either side of the assignment operator. I find `x := y` is generally more readable than `x:=y`. Also I think the industry standard for indentation is 2 or 4 (and I'm personally not keen on 2), and anything less or more than that looks unnecessarily weird.

Within your function, you might consider changing

```
where substr(first_name,1,1) = v_char;
```

to

```
where first_name like v_char||'%';
```

to take advantage of any index on `first_name`. (It will also allow you to pass a string of more than one character.)

By the way, the usual convention is to use a `v_` prefix for variables ('v' for *variable*, or sometimes 'l' for *local variable*), and something else for parameters (usually `p_`, or sometimes `in_`/`out_`/`inout_`).

Putting all that together gives:

```
create or replace function charcount
    ( p_matchstring in varchar2 )
    return varchar2
is
    l_num_matching number;
begin
    select count(*) into l_num_matching
    from   employees
    where  first_name like p_matchstring||'%';

    return l_num_matching;
end charcount;
```

Call from SQL*Plus or other client that supports substitution variables:

```
SQL> declare
  2      v_char varchar2(1) := '&textinput';
  3      v_count number;
  4  begin
  5      v_count := charcount(v_char);
  6      dbms_output.put_line(v_count);
  7  end;
  8  /
Enter value for textinput: A
10
```

or even just

```
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(charcount('&textinput'));
end;
```

or (using the [SQL*Plus `exec[ute]` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/EXECUTE.html) - though this is not part of SQL or PL/SQL):

```
exec dbms_output.put_line(charcount('&textinput'))
```

or the [SQL standard `call` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CALL.html):

```
call dbms_output.put_line(charcount('&textinput'));
```

Comment: How to use If condition to check  if the count > 1 then return v_count else return 0 in my Plsql function

Comment: @Bruno - that is not hard to do; but if the count is = 1, why do you want the function to return 0? That makes no sense.

Comment: To fully explain the error the OP received: When calling the function as he did, the PL/SQL interpreter sees the call `v_count := charcount(G)`. The function takes a `varchar2` argument; so it expects `G` to resolve to a varchar2 value. It is not a string itself (it is not enclosed in single-quotes); instead, it is a non-quoted string, which in PL/SQL means it must be an identifier. In this case, it must be a variable. If the function was called in SQL instead, such as in `select charcount(G) from dual`, he would get a different error: "invalid identifier".

Comment: In both cases the issue is the same: G must be a variable, or a column name - and there is no variable G in the anonymous PL/SQL block, resp. there is no column G in DUAL.

Comment: Executing function using plsql block:                                                             
declare 
  v_char char;
  v_count number;
begin
  v_char:='&v_char';
  v_count:=charcount(v_char);
  if(v_count>=1) then
    dbms_output.put_line('Number of employees having name starting with'||' '||v_char||'='||v_count);
  else 
    dbms_output.put_line('No such employee name start with'||' '||v_char);
  end if;
end;

Comment: when I give char which is does not start with Z at that time it shows PLS-00905:object HR.CHARCOUNT is invalid.

Comment: Whether the function is valid or invalid will not depend on the parameters passed into it. If it’s invalid there will be compilation errors.